# Cursoradapter listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

In my application, I am trying to show values from database in a `listview`. I am not able to add data into the `cursoradapter`.  I referred to code from simple adapter example, but with the `cursoradapter` I am facing a problem (nothing is showing in the activity).

Here is my code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.report);  
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
startManagingCursor(c); 
String[] from = new String[] { db.KEY_INCOME,db.KEY_DESC};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1 ,R.id.text2};
SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.columnview, c, from, to);
//System.out.println("notes="+notes.getCount());
setListAdapter(notes);
```

My mainXml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#bfffdf"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
```

My column xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textColor="#00ff00" 
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="110dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You must be getting some Exception in Logcat..Check it out and paste here.

Comment: I am not getting any exception there.I think the problem is in setListAdapter(notes);-->this is may for only simple adapter.But i am using cursor adapter.

Comment: Check what c.getCount(); is returning using logs.maybe your cursor does not hold any records.

Comment: thanks Vipul Shah.Problem lies there.Now i got to 50% of my answer,,

Comment: Vipul Shah ..one more help ..Based on above code can you help me to place the text2(in columnview.xml) somewhat gap between text1 and text2.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```